# open a specified path in cmd in windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmd, explorer

I want to open a specified path in vscode in windows 10 and I know there is a command that do this:
**`path> code .`**
but my problem is, how can I open a specified path in cmd Quickly even from explorer like in ubuntu without type any command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this very simple by type cmd and enter in your windows explorer address bar when you navigated to your specific folder in explorer.

1. [open specific folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EK9L.png)
2. [enter cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP9aQ.png)
3. [enter vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaRw5.png)

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Windows users

1. Add to path system Environment variables the VS code folder "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code"
2. Type "code ." in address bar of desired folder path of file explorer
3. VS code opens in that location

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in windows:

1. go to the folder which you want open vscode in that.
2. in the address bar, type "`cmd`" then press Enter.
3. in the cmd, type "`code .`" then press Enter.

Then, the vscode will open, while that folder will be opened by the vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution, no need for extra config or typing in different windows.
Just type in Address Bar:

```
code.cmd
```